# Simple java-wx webservice using javaee tutorial

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, wsdl

Im trying to build a simple webservice following this tutorial but unable to access the WSDL once I deploy the code in tomcat -

Here are the steps I followed -

1. Create a Dynamic web project in Eclipse.
2. Created a package and class..Here is the below code

   ```
   package helloservice.endpoint;

   import javax.jws.WebService;
   import javax.jws.WebMethod;

   @WebService
   public class Hello {
      private String message = new String("Hello, ");

      public void Hello() { }

      @WebMethod
      public String sayHello(String name) {
         return message + name + ".";
      }
   }
   ```
3. Deployed the code in tomcat and ran it but unable to access the WSDL. I went to the tomcat manager and see the "helloservice" application.

> ```
> **http://localhost:8080/helloservice/HelloService?wsdl**
> ```

From the document, what is `HelloService` after the `helloservice`. Is it the class name?

How can I debug it?

Comment: "unable to access the wsdl": what happens when you try to open http://localhost:8080/helloservice/HelloService?wsdl in the browser?

Comment: Roll up your sleeves and dig in to those tomcat logs!